# speeding up requiring modules in node/express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-modules

I'm trying to improve startup time of my node/express app.

I noticed that requiring some of the modules takes quite long:

```
    tracer: 2490.321ms
    createError: 73.287ms
    express: 975.461ms
    expressHbs: 2592.473ms
    path: 0.050ms
    cookieparser: 22.411ms
    logger: 57.616ms
    objection: 1219.993ms
    knex: 883.697ms
    knexConfig: 4.241ms
    passport: 92.907ms
    session: 127.029ms
    RedisStore: 65.394ms
    app.js: 10214.760ms
```

modules are required like this:

```
const express = require('express');
```

I'm running my application from a docker container locally on a macbook pro.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.0
RUN npm i npm@latest -g && npm i -g sass knex pm2
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-dev"]
```

How can I speed up the loading process?

Comment: did you created separate layer for your npm i command by copying the package.json? also what is npm run start-dev command doing here ?

Comment: npm run start-dev runs the npm i and starts the app. Measuring loading times from when the app is started excluding the npm i. Not sure what you mean with copying the package.json?

Comment: added a answer please upvote if works and let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Include all the dependencies in package.json and rewrite Dockerfile as following

FROM node:10.16.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "./"]
RUN npm i --production && mv node_modules ../
COPY ..
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-dev"]